# "Script References" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

The last few versions of visual studio have had the option to have a `references` type area, by default `/scripts/_references.js` that tracks all of your javascript for purposes of ... I guess knowing where they are, for intellisense and things.

Alright, that is fine. But this is not how everyone's projects are structured.

So I go exploring, and I find the happy `Tools->Options->Text Editor->Javascript-Intellisense` series of commands that seems to be amicably allowing me to tell it where I want these references to be!

However, even giving it my path, Visual Studio just gives me a big middle finger and ignores it. It continues to only care about the default `~/scripts/_references.js`.

Is there anything I can do about this? It is getting really obnoxious. Why even bother with the dialog to change it if that cannot work?

Examples of it not working; Intellisense is in no way impacted by javascript files references appropriately in the other files. The "auto sync" feature does not work on anything except something hard coded into the `~/scripts/_references.js` file. There is **literally** nothing that occurs from changing the location.

[image]

Comment: Some things you might try - moving the custom references.js higher using the up arrow and double checking that you have correctly entered the relative path to that file. You could also try completely removing the _references.js file and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I have tried this, and it does nothing.

Comment: Hey, great news! I contacted Microsoft directly and they said a Fix will be in the final release of Update 2!

Comment: So what is the appropriate way to handle this situation? My question was answered by Microsoft technical support, but others might still want to know this. However I do not want to look like a poor stackoverflow user by just leaving an open question. Can someone of better repute advise me on the correct and appropriate protocol for this?

Comment: @Ciel Could you answer your own question with the resolution that Microsoft tech support gave you? I'm running into this same problem as well on VS2013 Update 4

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to look at is your spelling of the file. MS uses `'_references.js'`. You called yours `'references.js'`. It may be the leading `_` that triggers the magic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the ~/scripts/_references.js from the Included files list in the Options dialog?

I'm also having trouble getting IntelliSense working correctly for js files.